# .NET Sample VCF Reader

Tags: c#, .net, vcf-vcard

Does anyone know of a good sample (inline in reply, or web tutorial) for extracting data from a VCF file using C#/.NET?

Does anyone use VCF files anymore?  Is this even worth doing for a contact management system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a little surprised that this isn't built into the .NET Framework anywhere, but I did find this tutorial, which I plan to use:

[.NET VCF Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vCardReader.aspx)

Comment: Luckily VCF is really simple!