# How to read a VCF (contact) file using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, contacts, vcf-vcard

We need a way to read (and, optionally, write) a .vcf file by using Delphi/Pascal code. A free library with source code would be perfect.

Comment: There is a standart so you can try to write parser by yourself. It doesn't seem difficult.

Comment: I that case, Google for something like "vcf file spec vcard contact" to avoid confusion with the Variant Call Format from genomics, and you find e.g. this spec: www.imc.org/pdi/vcard-21.rtf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364612/net-sample-vcf-reader?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593309/vcf-vcard-import-c-sharp?rq=1 may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AceVCard is free open component for delphi 2009 compatible with VCard 3.0 specifications:
http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=524